# WordPress not syncing Plugins/themes with whats inside FTP

Tags: wordpress, ftp, themes

This is the first time this happens to me.

I uploaded a WordPress theme via FTP to wp-content/themes and it's not showing on my WordPress backend.

I then deleted plugins from the backend and 1 theme then refreshed my FTP and they are still there.

It seems my FTP isn't syncing with my WordPress installation

Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Check folder permission. remove cache file

Comment: I'm currently turning the file permission of WP-content to 777 in addition to all the subdirectories. will that do the trick?

Comment: Try to change folder permission 755 and check

Comment: The thing is that the original permission was 755